# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter

Tags: java, jersey

I'm working on Rest service call with JERSEY version 2.22.1.

Below is the exception that is thrown.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter
```

**CONFIGURATION:**

```
  <!-- javax.ws.rs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jersey -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-simple-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Comment: share complete stack trace

Comment: Please provide more information to help up reproduce the problem. In it's current state, this post (question) is not answerable, hence I am voting to close it. For future reference, please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting another question. And please try to fix this one.